# Is there a way to display "All" for Kendo drop down list when a user come to the page with this drop down list

Tags: kendo-ui, dropdown

I want to configure OS Version dropdown list to display "All", so when the user first comes to this Page he should see "All" in the Dropdown for "OS Version". It seems that Kendo dropdown list does not have space holder feature, so I wonder is there any other way to make this works?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9K8b5.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should configure its optionLabel property.
See: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#configuration-optionLabel